# Learnable weighted mean operation in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, word-embedding

I was getting familiar with the notion of word embeddings and was trying to build a classifier in pytorch to do the same. While going through certain codes on GitHub, I noticed the following.

```py
class EmbeddingCls(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, num_class):
    super().__init__()
    self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(embed_dim, num_class)

def forward(self, x):
    # size of x: (batch_size, sequence_length)
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x = torch.mean(x,dim=1)
    out = self.fc1(x)
    return out
```

I understand why we are using `torch.mean(x, dim = 1)`. We just want to bring down the sequence length to the length of the embedding dimension. What I wanted to try was, to define a `max_length` parameter, concatenate the input x with zeros in order for x to have a dimension of `(batch_size, max_length)`. Then when it passes through the `self.embedding`, it should return a tensor of size `(batch_size, max_length, embedding_dim)`. Now instead of using `torch.mean(x, dim = 1)`, I would like to use a learnable weighted mean operation at dimension 1. Any idea how to do it in pytorch ?

The main reason I'm trying to do this, is because performing `torch.mean` is like giving equal importance to all the words in a sentence, I understand that it does little harm in the end, however, I would still like to know how the result would change if I used trainable weights instead of using `torch.mean`.

I wrote the following code with a bit of addons, however I think the problem lies in the `self.fc1` parameter.

```py
class EmbeddingClassifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, num_classes, max_length = 20):
    super().__init__()
    self.max_length = max_length
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(max_length, embedding_dim)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, num_classes)
  def forward(self, x):
    """
      x: pytorch LongTensor object of input_ids
      Note: x is of size --> (batch_size, sequence_length)
    """
    if x.shape[1] < self.max_length:
      zs = self.max_length - x.shape[1] # these many zeros are needed
      z = torch.zeros(size = (x.shape[0], zs), dtype = torch.int)
      x = torch.cat([x, z], dim = 1) # size of x: (batch_size, max_length)
    x = self.embedding(x) # (batch_size, max_length, embedding_dim)
    x = self.relu(self.fc1(x)) # (batch_size, embedding_dim)
    out = self.fc2(x) # (batch_size, embedding_dim)
    return out
```

Following error popped up:

> RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (200x5 and
> 20x5)

What I expect: I want the model to learn a tensor of size `(max_length,)`, say `[w_1,w_2,...w_n]`, which when operated on x (size of x: `(batch_size, max_length, embedding_dim)`) outputs a tensor of size `(batch_size, embedding_dim)`. Basically a replacement of torch.mean with trainable parameters.